# Xamarin.Forms Target Framework (Kitkat) Issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a project in Xamarin Forms which was started with Target Framework as Oreo i.e 8.0. But my app was constantly crashing on lower end devices hence I decided to downgrade to Android 4.4 as my target Framework. I downgraded all my nuget packages to suitable versions. But I still get following errors:

```
max res 19, skipping values-v21 "max res 19, skipping values-v21" in aapt.exe           
max res 19, skipping values-ldltr-v21 "max res 19, skipping values-ldltr-v21" in aapt.exe           
max res 19, skipping drawable-v21 "max res 19, skipping drawable-v21" in aapt.exe           
max res 19, skipping values-v23 "max res 19, skipping values-v23" in aapt.exe   
max res 19, skipping values-v22 "max res 19, skipping values-v22" in aapt.exe   
max res 19, skipping drawable-v23 "max res 19, skipping drawable-v23" in aapt.exe
max res 19, skipping anim-v21 "max res 19, skipping anim-v21" in aapt.exe           
max res 19, skipping values-v23 "max res 19, skipping values-v23" in aapt.exe   
max res 19, skipping color-v23 "max res 19, skipping color-v23" in aapt.exe 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:elevation' in values.xml
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xamarin.Forms requirements are that you **have** to use the **latest** Android compile and target API level....

> Additionally, the target/compile version for **Android projects must be set to Use latest installed platform.** However the minimum version can be set to API 15 so you can continue to support devices that use Android 4.0.3 and newer. These values are set in the Project Options:

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/installation?tabs=vswin#android

Comment: So I cannot compile using any other version other than Oreo at the moment?

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover . Do you know any issue relating xamarin apps crashing in android version < 5 and MI devices?

Comment: @Subash No I do not, post a new question with the exception/stacktrace that you are getting on that device(s) or the logcat crash/error that is occurring. That way we can at least see if it is user-code related, device related, etc... possibly an issue that Xamarin will need to address : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 1):

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:elevation' in values.xml

You should change your target at least 5.0 because elevation attribute came into picture in android 5.0 only. So with kit-kat it not going to work.
Either remove elevation or change your target version.

Comment: The problem is i do not have a `values.xml` file.

Comment: From your log I guess that. Than what is issue?

Comment: I am confused too.

Comment: That is only issue, In your log rest of all warnings & last one is error. Try to target your app to latest version.

Comment: Thank you @Arvindraja but the answer solves it although I have another issue now :( .